# Renaming files in subdirectories deletes the files

Tags: linux, bash

I am writing a script that renames *.MP4 files on an inserted SD card and then rsyncs them.

The directory with the *.MP4 files does not always have the same name:
eg: it could be /DCIM/123_PANA/ or /DCIM/141_PANA/ etc
So I'm trying to write a script that will see what folders are in the /DCIM path, and rename all the *.MP4 files, (there is also a MISC folder in this path which I suspect is causing the issue)
I am using a couple of variables to rename the files also

What I have is:

```
for f in /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/*; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        echo $f
        for file in $(find $f -name 'P*.MP4')
        do
            echo $file  ">" $(dirname "${file}")/$(date +"%d")$cardname$(basename $file)
            mv $file $(dirname "${file}")/$(date +"%d")$cardname$(basename $file)
        done
    fi
done
```

But what seems to happen is I end up with a single file with the prefix only (say 08_nb1_) in the _PANA folder, all the others have been deleted. Obviously this is not my desired result!

UPDATE:
$cardname is of the format `_nb2_`
When I do as asked replace mv with echo here is the output:

```
/media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410192.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410192.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410193.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410193.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410194.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410194.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410195.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410195.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410196.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410196.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410197.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410197.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410198.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410198.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410199.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410199.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410200.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410200.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410201.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410201.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410202.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410202.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410203.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410203.MP4
mv /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/P1410204.MP4 /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/141_PANA/09_nb2_P1410204.MP4
/media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/MISC
```

Comment: first fix (and update your Q) with any corrections from https://shellcheck.net . Good luck.

Comment: Please show in your question an example of the existing files and the script's output. To avoid modifying your files you can remove the existing `echo $file...` and replace `mv $file $(dirname...` with `echo mv $file $(dirname...`

Comment: `$cardname` is not shown. Might it contain a space?

Comment: thanks for the help - please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

OK I fixed it by filtering the additional directory names and limiting to only the ones with *_PANA  - which solved the issue. I also added a the rsync part and demounted the SD card (if required using Zenity)

A text file placed on the SD card identifies it as a unique card giving each file a unique name when rsyncing it to the backup folder. Renaming on the SD card means
that it can still be used an written to if not full, but we then know which files have been backed up.
Very useful in the field when filming with multiple cards, crews. All running on a Rpi4

```
for f in /media/pi/LUMIX/DCIM/*_PANA/; do
    if [ -d "$f" ]; then
        echo "$f"

                for file in $(find $f -wholename '*_PANA/P*.MP4')
                do

                mv "$file" $(dirname "${file}")/$(date +"%d")"$cardname"$(basename "${file}")
    done
        rsync --stats -u --progress "$f"/*.MP4 /media/pi/VDRIVE/ | tee /home/pi/Documents/ytu/rsync.txt  | zenity  --icon-name="dialog-warning" \
        --width=300 --progress --pulsate --auto-close --auto-kill \
         --title="Copying $sdn" 
        zenity --question --text="Unmount Card?"
        if [ $? = 0 ]; then
                umount /media/pi/LUMIX
        else
                exit
        fi

    fi
done
```